# UnityReportWWWFinishedLoadingData Xcode crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, xcode7.1

I have been stuck on this issue for the last two days. I'm using Unity 5.2.3f1 and calling a URL through WWW(URL) class. The URL uses https so it is SSL secured. The file that I'm retrieving is a simple plist file that I've placed in my dropbox account. The call is made inside a coroutine and the result is expected in a yield statement. I've also added App Allow Transport Property in Info.plist file and allowed Arbitrary Loads true in it.

However whenever I try to retrieve the data, my app crashes halting at FeedUnityWebStream after UnityReportWWWFinishedLoadingData.

**Crash log is as following:**

Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 16e677000 -> priority: 1 
2015-11-30 15:53:58.278 3dgymnastics[1029:280327] -[**NSMallocBlock** bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13898d260
2015-11-30 15:53:58.368 3dgymnastics[1029:280327] Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: -[**NSMallocBlock** bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13898d260
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185b7cf60  + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019a63ff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185b83c5c  + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185b80c00  + 872
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185a84cac _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   3dgymnastics                        0x000000010043fe08 _ZN3WWW18FeedUnityWebStreamEb + 104
    6   3dgymnastics                        0x00000001006796a8 UnityReportWWWFinishedLoadingData + 68
    7   CFNetwork                           0x000000018540f6a8  + 80
    8   CFNetwork                           0x000000018540f638  + 200
    9   CFNetwork                           0x000000018540f7ac  + 56
    10  CFNetwork                           0x000000018527b4fc  + 100
    11  CFNetwork                           0x0000000185369b38  + 108
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101e7dc68 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101e8740c _dispatch_block_invoke + 564
    14  CFNetwork                           0x0000000185267ce4  + 36
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185a606cc CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    16  CFNetwork                           0x0000000185267bc8  + 136
    17  CFNetwork                           0x0000000185267a88  + 312
    18  CFNetwork                           0x00000001852678b4  + 68
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185b34544  + 24
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185b33f58  + 412
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185b31cd8  + 724
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185a60ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000190c9c088 GSEventRunModal + 180
    24  UIKit                               0x000000018b178ffc UIApplicationMain + 204
    25  3dgymnastics                        0x0000000100053100 main + 144
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000019ae8e8b8  + 4
)
2015-11-30 15:53:58.369 3dgymnastics[1029:280327] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13898d260'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185b7cf48 0x19a63ff80 0x185b83c5c 0x185b80c00 0x185a84cac 0x10043fe08 0x1006796a8 0x18540f6a8 0x18540f638 0x18540f7ac 0x18527b4fc 0x185369b38 0x101e7dc68 0x101e8740c 0x185267ce4 0x185a606cc 0x185267bc8 0x185267a88 0x1852678b4 0x185b34544 0x185b33f58 0x185b31cd8 0x185a60ca0 0x190c9c088 0x18b178ffc 0x100053100 0x19ae8e8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I know the problem is related to security settings recently introduced by Apple in iOS9. The work around I have been using till now is by adding NSAppTransportSecurity. However it just won't work anymore. Need help in the matter.

My Unity version is 5.2.3 and Xcode is 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct approach but I finally managed to get it working. I was turning ARC setting off to allow few files with retain. Something I should never have done since a simple separate flags for these files in Build Phases can get it done. On turning ARC back on, the rest of the program worked without errors. Newbie or rookie mistake to make. Unity5 onwards turns on ARC by default. I guess a lot depends on it in exported Xcode project. Hopefully this helps someone if they encounter something similar.